# Custom MySQL Default Value

Tags: mysql

Is it possible for a MySQL Table Field to have a Default Value like this:
13-001
The first 2 digits is the last 2 digits of the current year, e.g. 2013 = 13

The last 3 digits is the maximum count of rows + 1 with the same first 2 digits, and is zero-filled.
So when the Current Year Changed and the last Value is 13-461, the next value would be 14-001.

The **tblPurchase** table has 3 fields:
**PRKey**: Auto-Increment INT
**PRDate**: Current_Timestamp
**PRNo**: VARCHAR(6) 'This will contain the 13-999 value

Comment: Can you use `TRIGGER`s with you database?

Comment: @t.niese I haven't thought of that, can you post an answer using triggers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @Barmar, settings the 13-999 as default value isn't possible.
The MySQL Trigger mentioned by @t.niese is a bit tricky but I'm getting there.

I came up with a solution to include the 13-999 value during INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO tblPurchase(PRNo, other_fields_here)
SELECT
  CONCAT(
    RIGHT(YEAR(CURDATE()),2),
    '-',
    LPAD(CAST(COUNT(PRKey) + 1 AS DECIMAL,3,'0')
  ),
  other_fields_here
FROM
  tblPurchase
WHERE
  Year(PRDate)=YEAR(CURDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

No. The default has to be a literal value, or one of a few special built-in functions (like `current_timestamp` for `timestamp` columns).

Comment: Thanks. I will be looking into TRIGGERs instead.

Answer (score 0):

The table structure is a little bit different to yours (I started to write this before you posted your structure - I use a datetime field), but i think you still should get an idea how it could work:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `TestTable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `no` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

And here the `INSERT` trigger.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `Test` BEFORE INSERT ON `TestTable`
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE c INT;
    SET c = (SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 FROM TestTable WHERE YEAR(date)=YEAR(NOW()));
    SET NEW.date = NOW();
    SET NEW.no = CONCAT( SUBSTR(YEAR(NOW()),-2) ,"-", LPAD(c,3,'0') );
  END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

But you should probably think over another structure and split your `PRNo`  field into a `year` and a `number` field and only use the counting part to create a *auto increment per year*

Comment: I will definitely look into this. Thank you.

Comment: @Ruben you need to check yourself if the `COUNT(*) + 1` would fit your requirements. It e.g. would fail if you delete entries in the current year because then you will get conflicting numbers. But because you wrote `maximum count of rows + 1` I assumed that this would not happen.